# Need help from Flash/AS people

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

Let me preface by saying I have no Flash/AS knowledge really at all.  My boss built a site in Flash and is asking if I can figure out how to load images into a gallery using XML and animating the images.  I have no idea where to start, but since I'm our web developer, I'm trying to come up with something.  Let me know if you have any guidance.  Thanks!

The flash file can be found at http://www.sparktoignite.com/jace.fla

Comment: That file should not even be opened, this is a community site and is for the betterment of all. If you are having a problem with a piece of the ActionScript Code or Fla you need to place it here. Also you need to change that title **everyone** here who posts a question needs help . Putting help in the title does not make it special. Take a step back from the fla file and breathe. If you have some Object Oriented experience you should be fine. If not, you need to out source it unless you are ready to stick your head into the ECMA hole.

Comment: Nice horse there buddy.  Looks pretty high.

But seriously, I do appreciate the input, even if it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need several skills for this:

- how to load and read xml files
- how to load and add images to stage
- how to animate things in flash

they are also planty of tutorials about this areas. e.g. you search the site http://active.tutsplus.com/

Comment: I have some decent XML knowledge and have read some tuts on loading content via XML.  I'm not too sure about much else from there.  Not knowing Flash/AS, I just was looking to see if there was a quick, easy way to do it.  Seems like there isn't, so I'll do some more research when I get a chance.  Thanks for the advice!